In the healing of the hemorrhaging woman in Matthew 9:22, why do English translators imply that this was after Jesus spoke with her?
Why do modern English translations inject a chronological contradiction between Mark 5:29/Luke 8:44 and Matthew 9:22? Did the blood flow dry up before or after Jesus spoke to the woman?

And there was a woman who had had a discharge of blood for twelve years ... [she] came up behind him in the crowd and touched his garment. And immediately [Mark: euthus; Luke: parachrēma] the flow of blood dried up ... And Jesus, perceiving in himself that power had gone out from him, immediately turned about in the crowd and said, “Who touched my garments?” (Mark 5:25–30 ESV)


And behold, a woman ... touched the fringe of his garment ... Jesus turned, and seeing her he said, “Take heart, daughter; your faith has made you well.” And instantly the woman was made well. (Matthew 9:20–22 ESV).

The NASB, NIV, NLT, LSB, CSB, and NRSB offer similar translations, implying that the the healing instantly followed the dialog.
Why have these translations chosen "and instantly" for the sentence (Matt. 9:22) which follows the dialog?
Rarely would I assert that the KJV offers a better translation than modern translations, but perhaps this is a lesson that one must be extra careful to understand the collateral impacts--such as unnecessarily introducing contradictions between the synoptics--when moving away from a literal translation.
As expressed in the Greek (and KJV), the healing is from that hour, not from the moment after which Jesus spoke.

But Jesus ... said, "Daughter ..." And the woman was made whole from that hour (apo tēs hōras ekeinēs). (Matt. 9:22 KJV)

The NET and a few other modern translations follow the KJV.

Answer
In the case of the healing of the hemorrhaging woman, Mark 5:29, Luke 8:44 and Matthew 9:22 all say the same thing: that the healing took place before Jesus spoke with her.
Explanation
Mark’s narration:
The woman had the problem of blood flow for twelve years. She consulted many physicians and spent a lot for the treatment. But the problem worsened only. She heard about Jesus and decided that if only she could touch His garment, she would be healed. So, in the crowd, she did just that.
Immediately her disease was healed and she knew it.
Jesus, realizing that power went out from Him, enquires and sees the situation.
The woman got frightened and “knowing what had happened on her” (healing) tells the whole things to Jesus (verse 33).

“And He said to her, Daughter, your faith has (already) healed
you. Go in peace and be whole from your plague” (verse 34).

Jesus here acknowledges that she has already been healed from her blood issue.
Then He blesses her to “be whole”, that is, be restored from the mental and physical trauma she had undergone for 12 long years.
There is no contradiction here.
Luke’s narration:
Very much the same narration as we see in Mark. When she touches the fringe of His garment, she is instantly healed.
Jesus enquires who touched Him. The frightened woman tells Him the whole incident “and how she was instantly cured” (verse 47).

“And He (Jesus) said to her, Daughter, be comforted (be whole).
Your faith has (already) healed you. Go in peace” (verse
48).

There again is no contradiction here.
Matthew’s narration:
A woman with a problem of blood issue for 12 years comes and touches the fringe of His robe. She had earlier decided that if she could touch Jesus’s garment, she would be healed.
[Now Matthew does not narrate what transpired between her touching and Jesus’s seeing her. Silence does not mean that this didn’t happen]

“And Jesus having turned about, and having seen her, said, 'Be of
good courage (be whole), daughter, thy faith hath saved
(G4982=Sozo) thee,' and the woman was saved (G4982=Sozo) from that
hour” (verse 23; YLT).

That woman was not simply healed; she was “saved” from that debilitating disease. The blood issue will not recur.
The same Greek word G4982 is used here when the disciples in a boat got caught in a terrible storm:

“And coming near, His disciples aroused Him, saying, Lord, save
(G4982=Sozo) us! We are perishing” (Mat 8:25).

Again, there is no contradiction here.
Conclusion
In all the three narratives there is not an iota of contradiction.

She is instantly healed when she touches Jesus’s garment;

Jesus identifies her, talks to her and acknowledges that she is already healed because of her faith; and

Jesus, as usual, makes her whole and “saves” her for life from that crippling disease, mentally and physically.


There is no chronological contradiction.

From the three verse quoted by the OP, we have the sequence of events:

the woman approaches Jesus from behind
the woman touches the fringe/hem of Jesus garment
the woman is healed and Jesus senses power has gone out of Him for the healing
Jesus turns around in order to find the person responsible
Jesus talks to the woman

Now, the difficulty that the OP appears to be having arises from the misleading translation of the ESV, which, despite it claims to the contrary, is not literal in Matt 9:22.
Here is BSB literal translation of Matt 9:22 -

And Jesus, having turned and having seen her said, "Take courage,
daughter. Your faith has cured you." And the woman was cured from that
very hour.

Notice that there is nothing about "instantly", nor "from that moment" in the Greek text.

Although Bible's authors were divine inspired, each piece of writing still reflects the author's unique characteristics. Therefore, there might be slight variations in the arrangement of the same event.
In the healing of the hemorrhaging woman, Dottard's answer already depicts the sequence of events, and the entire episode concludes quickly. It is possible that the authors focused on recording details rather than adhering strictly to chronological order.
In the Gospels, all of Jesus' healings are purposeful and done with His knowledge, except for the healing of the hemorrhaging woman, who interrupted Jesus as He was on His way to raise the daughter of a synagogue leader from death. The incident reveals a truth: the power of healing does not depends solely on Jesus' spoken word. The power comes from within, which is believed to be the Holy Spirit, as Jesus proclaims in John 8:29;

The one who sent me is with me; he has not left me alone, for I always do what pleases him.”

The healing must have been instant when the woman touched Jesus' cloak and the Lord's power responded to her. Jesus' words, "Daughter, your faith has healed you" (Matthew 9:22; Mark 5:34 and Luke 8:48) affirm her faith in Jesus, as she thought, that "If I just touch His clothes, I will be healed" (Matthew 9:21; Mark 5:28 and Luke 8:47)
